# Preventing rspec trying to connect to mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I am running rails with mongoid as my db with the connections in my mongoid.yml file.

The problem is that every time I run rspec it tries to connect to the mongodb back end.

I want to stop this behaviour and use mocks for my tests.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide some example code?

Answer (score 0):

For unit tests in rspec if you are making Mongoid persistence calls on your model objects, you will need to replace those persistence calls with calls to a mocking/stubbing library instead. For instance, [factory-girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) provides mock-implementations of your model objects, which you can then use in your unit tests by calling non-persistent methods ala...

```
person = FactoryGirl.build(:person)
person.should be_a_kind_of Person
```

Avoid calling methods that persist to the test database, such as 'FactorGirl.create'